# Adequate number of threads for a networking/database job

Tags: java, networking, io, multitasking

I have a job that does the following tasks around 10000 times:

1) HTTP request (1 second)

2) Data transformation (0.3 second)

3) Database insert (0.7 second)

The total time it tasks for every iteration is around 2 seconds, distributed as mentionned above.

I'd like to do multitasking but I'm wondering what would be the optimal number of threads for such jobs (4 cores processor) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your task's profile is as follows:

- 1.7 seconds spent in blocking state;
- 0.3 seconds spent engaging the CPU.

That means that the task imposes a 15% average load on the CPU, which makes the CPU a relatively minor concern in your approach to speeding up the process as a whole. Your performance will probably not be limited by the computing power of your machine, but rather by the concurrent performance characteristics of the two external systems you depend on.

Conclusion: your question is unanswerable due to lack of key information. A possibly good approach is optimization by trial and error; however keep in mind that your performance my depend on a very large number of factors not under your control (they could stem from anywhere in the entire system consisting of the external machines and all the network interconnections).